# Finding group homomorphism from $\mathbb{C}$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

In case when a particular mapping $\phi$ is not given.

I just want to know what are the steps to be employed while proving homomorphism.

If $\phi$ is given, then one can prove the homomorphism as per the rules of definition. But my problem arises when no such mapping is given in the question.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: To prove there exists a group homomorphsim from $\mathbb{C}$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: This question is likely to be closed as "too vague". There is no set of "steps". Each problem will be about a particular pair of groups. You will have to use properties of those groups and intuition about homomorphisms to motivate the search. If you edit the question to provide a particular example that puzzles you, and show us what you have thought so far we may be able to help.

Comment: I have edited my question. How can I prove this now?

Comment: I assume you mean the additive groups. Hint: $\mathbb{R}$ is an additive subgroup of $\mathbb{C}$. What might you want for the image of $i$?

Comment: Sorry, I am not able to follow you! What mapping can I have in this case?

Comment: It's hard to give you more of a hint without answering the question. Do you think you can define $\phi$ by sending $1$ to itself and $i$ to $0$?

Answer (score 3):

> **Hint:** Consider $\pi:\Bbb C\to \Bbb R$, defined by $\pi(a+i b)=a.$

Answer (score 1):

Finding a group isomorphism between $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ is tricky and possibly not what you should be thinking about in the begginings of an introductory class to abstract algebra.

Anyway, consider them as vector spaces over $\mathbb{Q}$. A basis (which exists by axiom of choice) for either of these spaces necessarily has cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$. It can't be bigger: this is the cardinality of $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{R}$. And it can't be smaller: with less than $2^{\aleph_0}$ elements and the $\aleph_0$ elements of $\mathbb{Q}$, you can't produce, using only finite linear combinations, the $2^{\aleph_0}$ elements of $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$.

Take a bijection between these bases and this gives an isomorphism as vector spaces, which is particularly an isomorphism as groups.

I just noticed you only want a homomorphism, which can be found by simpler means. But maybe this answer is worth posting anyway.

Comment: Really so complicated? Consider $f\colon\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(z)=z+\bar{z}$.

Comment: @egreg That's not a bijection.

Comment: Is that required for a homomorphism?

Answer (score 0):

You must construct one! Although you may look at different  properties isomorphic groups have. Like Order of the group and orders of elements . Subgroups have the same properties too. If its a cyclic -abelian or not. And otheproperties. The definition says if there exists a map that.... .So you have to find a map. Ive never met a proof where it does prove its existance of this map .Whitoutfinding it. Now there are  other questions like. THere CANT be homomorphisms doing "that" or some other thing. Those questions are answered by using known facts and properties of the Homomorphsim. Combined with the structure of the given groups you get restrictions on the possible homomorphisms.
EDIT : This was an answer before the Question became finding a specific homomorphism.

Comment: You mean if for any one $\phi$ the group homorphism is proved,then it is generally true in every case?

Comment: @MB17 IF you find one map that does the homomorphism job then the groups are generally homomorphic!(Or isomorphic if the map is also injective)

Comment: So I have to search for that **one** map.. And I feel searching for that map is very difficult. Because If I get one map that disproves, then I cant say that  the group is not homomorphism.I got this. But now how can I disprove homomorphism?

Comment: @MB17 Just like i told you.Given groups.With certain properties you can get restrictions on your homomorphism. There is always One homomorphism. The trivial one .The map that send every element to identity of the other group. WHat is important is if there exist isomorphism. Homomoprhism always exists.